# Tableau | Display different sheets by selecting option(s) from one particular filter

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to display different sheets by clicking/selecting values/options from one particular filter?

for example, if I have this filter:

[image: filter by sectors]

and I need to display a sheet named Departments when I select Commercial from the filter shown in the PtrScn.

However, When I click/select any other options like HR, Information ...etc, I want it to display the associated sheet with the filter "Filter by Sector"

Any hints would be highly appreciated!

**NOTE**: I use tableau 2019.1 and it does not show "Change Parameter" that might be needed to approach this as I noticed when I have been researching for two days now!

Comment: did the answer solved your need? if so, please accept the answer in order to close the thread

Answer (score 2):

You should use a container (say vertical) where you wanna put your N worksheets one on top of the other one **without changing vertical spacing**: just let Tableau do its stuff!

Be sure to remove the worksheet titles.

Once you're done, you need to create a parameter in order to handle all the N possible choices, and according to that you need to create N Calculated fields with a condition like this one:

```
if [Param] = 'Profit' then 'ok' else 'ko' end
```

Each calculated field will be used as a condition (select just ok values) in your filter selection.

[image]

Since the parameter can accept just one value a time, you will have just one of your N worksheet displaying data.

And this is the trick based on the vertical conatiner: if you hide worksheet titles, you will see "something" just for the selected worksheet and Tableau automatically will handle all the vertical space in the container.

The result will look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Fabio's great answer, these resources about collapsing containers may be useful:

1. [Sheet swapping using collapsing containers](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-sheet-swapping/#parameter)
2. [Automatically resize items in a Tableau container](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-automatically-resize-tables-on-a-dashboard/) (or make disappear in your case)